# SnackBar click to dismiss

Tags: android, android-layout, android-snackbar

I need to create a SnackBar that requires the user to click to dismiss. How do I do that? The following won’t compile and I don’t want to make the SnackBar variable a field.

```
final Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.notAvailable),
                "You don't have this feature",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                snack.dismiss();
            }
        });
        snack.show();
```

Comment: If you want to use the action button for something else, you can dismiss the Snackbar by clicking elsewhere within the Snackbar, like this: `final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(yourView, yourMainText, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(yourActionText, yourActionOnClickListener);
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
snackbarView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        snackbar.dismiss();
    }
});
snackbar.show();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the normal onClick `Listener`. implement a click action and l**et it empty, empty dismiss the `sanckbar` itself** . Clicking on empty click action will dismiss `snackbar` .

> Sample Code.

```
Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayoutView, "Service Enabled", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("DISMISS", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
```

Comment: This is the correct approach to dismiss the Snackbar. However if you wish, you can have a Snackbar object and operate setAction() and show () methods on that for better understanding.

Comment: In order to keep the snackbar visible, it also needs the LENGTH_INDEFINITE attribute (as shown in questions code).

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: it does not matter if click handler is empty or has some lines of code - it will be executed and snackbar will dismiss automatically. This also works if LENGTH_INDEFINITE.